# Fetch groups data from Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am trying to fetch the groups data from facebook using the below code.

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/groups?fields=cover,name"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{
 if (!error) 
   {

   }
else
   {

   }
}
];
```

The issue here is, it doesn't return the results for some accounts which are logged in with Facebook. Could someone let me know the solution for this issue.